# Execute function if certain time is reached, Python's best approach

Tags: python, multithreading

I have thread which prints in infinite loop a variable value (e.g. `var_x = "Some string"`, `var_x` - is global).

If I change the value of `var_x`, the thread prints changed value instantly.

Let's assume that there are some time intervals e. g. 15 seconds. 
I want to get a result: when I change the value of `var_x` e.g. in the 5th second of the interval the thread shouldn't change it instantly but should wait till interval time ends (next 10 seconds).

What is the best approach in Python for that kind of problem?

Comment: Have you considered using a buffer?

Comment: Could you write more about how I can use a buffer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by creating two threads, which starts at the same time:

- Thread0 - DoSomethig
- Thread1 - TimeManager

Both threads run as a daemon and have infinite loops: thread0 prints value of a global variable, thread1 sleep some time interval then change value which prints thread0.

When you want to change the value you don't have direct access to printed variable but you can change value of temporary one. Thread1 assign temporary value to value which is printed.

Comment: This solution works for me. If it isn't clear enough please let me know I can prepare some code or diagrams in order to explain it.